# Extracting data from a dynamic html table using DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

First I wanna say that I'm new to javascript so this may look as a simple problem. I'm tring to extract data from a dynamically generated html table( table id ="tableId") using DOM. Each cell of the table includes an input field to get user input. The problem is below javascript returns "null" always when retrieving the input field value. What I'm doing wrong here?

```
var mytable       = document.getElementById('tableId');
var mytablebody = mytable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

var myrow   = mytablebody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
    var cell = myrow.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    var inputNode = cell.childNodes[0];
    var taskName  = inputNode.nodeValue; //??

    document.write("Task Name:" + taskName);
```

Thaks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('tableID').getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    alert(inputs[i].value);
}
```

text input fields (unless it's a textarea), don't really have a `.nodeValue`. The data entered into the form field is stored in `.value`.